# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get into Angular after a few months without programming and have decided to code a cascading dropdown menu. I was trying to do the second part of the cascade and my code was looking like this:

```
onSelect(event_type:any){
    this.dropdownListService.getAll().subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.properties = res['properties'].filter((res:any) => res.event_type == event_type!.value),
      console.log(this.properties);
    })
  }
```

The only problem is that I'm getting

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"

I can't understand, why is it undefined?

Comment: the properties object inside response is undefined, try a console.log and check the response of the api call!

Answer (score 1):

#### *I can't understand, why is it undefined?*

The simple reason is that the service response is ***undefined***. That is what the error says:

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"

This means `res['properties']` is not an Array but undefined.

You can add one `filter()` operator:

```
this.dropdownListService.getAll()
.pipe(
   filter(resp => resp !== undefined && resp !== null)
).subscribe((res:any)=>{
```

Or as the other answer says like have a condition to check in the subscription block.

<sup>*Use the condition as you like but better to debug why it is failing to give response.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just add Question mark after like res['properties']?.filter........

onSelect(event_type:any){
this.dropdownListService.getAll().subscribe((res:any)=>{
this.properties = res['properties']?.filter((res:any) => res.event_type == event_type!.value),
console.log(this.properties);
})
}

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 problems happened in your case. One is the `res['properties']` is not a json array and another one is `res['properties']` must be undefined. You can handle it like below,

```
onSelect(event_type:any){
    this.dropdownListService.getAll().subscribe((res:any)=>{
     if(res['properties'] != undefined && res['properties'].length > 0){
      this.properties = res['properties'].filter((res:any) => res.event_type == event_type!.value),
      console.log(this.properties);
     }
    })
  }
```